Convert decimal duration in hours (xxx.xxx) to time format duration in hours (hh:mm:ss)
All search results have so far pointed to DAX measures, even for those posts located in Power Query-specific forums. I would really like an M code solution.



Fuel Injection [°]
Speed [rpm]
Duration [h]






15
400
2.81




15
450
2.49




15
500
3.02




15
520
1.18




15
540
0.96




15
560
0.83




15
580
0.78




15
600
0.68




15
620
0.57




15
640
0.48




15
660
0.4




15
680
0.35




15
700
0.73




15
720
0.5




15
740
0.21




15
760
0.52




15
780
0.23




15
800
0.5




15
820
1.45




15
840
0.21




15
860
0.14




15
900
0.63




15
940
1.71




15
980
9.9




15
1020
2.56




15
1060
0.32




15
1100
0.31




15
1150
0.36




15
1200
0.21




15
1250
0.15




15
1300
0.08




15
1350
0.08




25
400
188.4




25
450
28.17




25
500
369.64




25
520
280.5




25
540
8.03




25
560
4.66




25
580
9.21




25
600
13.97




25
620
13.36




25
640
8.28




25
660
368.02




25
680
304.22




25
700
38.83




25
720
70.18




25
740
6.48




25
760
2.62




25
780
1.38




25
800
2.22




25
820
1.64




25
840
0.7




25
860
0.45




25
900
1.07




25
940
27.94




25
980
1068.64




25
1020
1.44




25
1060
0.52




25
1100
0.03




25
1150
0.64




25
1200
0




25
1250
0




25
1300
0




25
1350
0




30
400
226.74




30
450
35.11




30
500
356.27




30
520
270.5




30
540
39.96




30
560
32.85






For example, if testing with "2.81h", would you expect the following result?
Convert: 02:48:36
If it is correct, try this:
let
    Source = DataSource
    HoursColumn = Table.AddColumn(Source, "TimeFormatDuration", each Duration.From([Duration,h] * #duration(0, 0, 1, 0)))
in
    HoursColumn

And (from Davidebacci's comment):
Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each Duration.From([Duration] * #duration(0, 1, 0, 0))


Good solution. The duration is in the wrong place but this works: Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each Duration.From([Duration] * #duration(0, 1, 0, 0)))

My bad, thanks @davidebacci for your remark now I edit the answer.

Now I feel like a lazy idiot for not coming up with that. Thank you both, sirs! @BlackSD

Now I feel like a lazy idiot for not coming up with that. Thank you both, sirs! @davidebacci

Some results look like this: 0.13:33:35.9999999. Any way to round off?

@hic24 You're welcome! we're for help you don't worry about it. If you need to round the result or search nearest second add this after HoursColumn
RoundNum = Table.TransformColumns(HoursColumn, {{"TimeFormatDuration", each Duration.From(Number.Round(_, 0)), type duration}})
in
RoundNum
